# kafka group rebalancing takes a long time

Tags: apache-kafka

I am experencing with the group rebalancing taking very long time so that it is blocking  any consumer consumsing messages. 
my questions :

1. Why it is taking so much time to for group rebalancing?
2. how can I fix this issue? do I need to restart the kafka cluster? or any workaround solution for this as we are using the kafka cluster in production

below are screenshot:

```
bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9095 --new-consumer --describe --group command-consumer-ldnpsr000001135   --command-config config/consumer.config
Consumer group `command-consumer-ldnpsr000001135` is rebalancing.
```

appreciate for any advice?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 possible reasons for this:

1. when a consumer joins a group then there will start a rebalance process. there is a configuration for the number of retries: rebalance.max.retries and is set to 4 by default.
2. if the consumer fails to heartbeat to Zookeeper. ZooKeeper session timeout. ZooKeeper for this period of time it is considered dead and a rebalance will occur.

Comment: what happens if rebalance.max.retries is exceeded? will the group be stuck in the rebalancing state?